# Batch process on photos to be match based on eye positions

Tags: batch, images, adobe-photoshop

I'm not sure if this question related to this site.

I have a series of photos (faces) that are different in distance and pose from camera (all of them are selfies) want to match them based on eyes and put them as keyframes to make something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B26asyGKDo

Not sure if its possible with Photoshop Batch process (not sure what it can do)
Any idea or cue will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I do not believe that Adobe Photoshop supports any type of image processing algorithm to point out or find any particular part of the image automatically. So, finding eyes would be the first challenge then finding similarities would be more complicated. 
If the photos are not many (in number) you would have apply better control in order to achieve an artistic output, if you manage them manually. If the numbers are beyond the manual management, you need to look into image processing libraries or prototyping you may use MatLab with image processing abilities and libraries on face recognition. However, you have to be familiar with that environment. Then you may define an input to your algorithm from the files and obtain the altered ones. Though, I believe creating an algorithm that would work with a wide variety of poses and eyes would be time consuming. Therefore, it should be worth it.

Comment: Ah, Thank you for answer :)
They are about 100-150 image sequences!
I taught maybe Auto Align help, but that was not my solution
http://layersmagazine.com/image-sequences-in-photoshop.html

I think I need to sit and put them align manually :(